# How many different ways to form a triangle from $16$ points lying on the sides of a quadrilateral

Tags: combinatorics

> Four points are chosen on each side of a quadrilateral. How many triangles with vertices between these points can be formed (one of the sides of the triangle must lie on a side of the quadrilateral)? (Answer: $288$)

Can we say that for the first vertex we have $16$ options, for the second $12$ and for the third $8$? I guess in this count we are counting the same triangle three times. Should we divide by $3$?

We can calculate the total number of options if we did not have restrictions in this way: ${16 \choose 3}=560$.

P.P. Now I noticed that my first idea is not reasonable.

Comment: The answer that is given in my book is $288$.

Comment: And I think my first approach does not work. Because the third vertex of the triangle can lie on the first side.

Comment: In fact the question demands that the third vertex of the triangle *must* lie on the first side. First pick a side, then pick two points on it, then pick a point on one of the remaining three sides. You'll find $4\times\tbinom{4}{2}\times12=288$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am not sure I understand your solution. We can have a triangle in which vertices lie on three different sides of the quadrilateral.

Comment: The queston explicitly demands that one side of the triangle is on a side of the quadrilateral.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice this. :( Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the first vertex of the triangle,
number of choices=16

We will assume that the second vertex lies on the same side of the quadrilateral as the first vertex, since the question demands for the same. Note that this step does not affect the answer as the vertices are not numbered.
So number of choices for second vertex=3

The third vertex may lie on any of the remaining 3 sides of the quadrilateral, but not on the same side as the first 2 vertices, which will result in a line instead of a triangle.
So number of choices for vertex 3= 12

Combining all the choices for the 3 vertices, we get number of triangles= 16*3*12=576

Again, the first and second vertices can be used interchangeably as they are not numbered.
So to fix this, we divide the total number by 2, to get the desired result.
576/2= 288 triangles.